# Приложение вылетает с ошибкой: IllegalStateException: Could not execute method for android:onClick. Не могу понять почему

Tags: java, android, textview

Всем здравствуйте! Написал программу. Вроде всё правильно, но не могу понять, почему ошибка. Показывал код программисту, он тоже ничего такого не нашёл.
Код MainActivity:

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.DisplayMetrics;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.PopupWindow;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Random;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

ArrayList<String> spinner1 = new ArrayList<>();
ArrayList<String> spinner2 = new ArrayList<>();
EditText editText;
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter1;
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter2;
Spinner mainSpinner;
Spinner newSpinner;
Button button;
int i = 1;
String CurrentText;
int width = 0;
int ran1;
int ran2;
int ran3;
int ran4;
int ran5;
int ran6;
int ran7;
int ran8;
String str1;
String str2;
String str3;
String str4;
String str5;
String str6;
String str7;
String str8;
String str9;
String str10;
boolean block = true;
Random r = new Random();
TextView textview;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.EditText);
    mainSpinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.MainSpinner);
    newSpinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.NewSpinner);
    button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Button);
    final DisplayMetrics metrics = getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
    width = metrics.widthPixels;
    textview = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);



    // адаптер MainSpinner
    adapter1 = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, spinner1);
    adapter1.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    mainSpinner.setAdapter(adapter1);
    // адаптер NewSpinner
    adapter2 = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, spinner2);
    adapter2.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    newSpinner.setAdapter(adapter2);
}

private void initiatePopupWindow() {
    try {
        textview = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) MainActivity.this.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.standardscrapyard, (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.popup_element));
        PopupWindow pwindo = new PopupWindow(layout, width, 180, true);
        pwindo.showAtLocation(layout, Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
public void delay() {
    try {
        Thread.sleep(600);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public void onClick(View button) {
    CurrentText = (editText.getText().toString());
    if (i == 1) {
        spinner1.add(editText.getText().toString());
        adapter1.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        mainSpinner.setAdapter(adapter1);
    } else {
        spinner2.add(editText.getText().toString());
        adapter2.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        newSpinner.setAdapter(adapter2);
    }
    if (CurrentText.equals("12345")) {
        newSpinner.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        i = 2;
    }
    if (CurrentText.equals("2014")) {
        ran8 = r.nextInt(90000000) + 10000000;
        ran7 = r.nextInt(9000000) + 1000000;
        ran6 = r.nextInt(900000) + 100000;
        ran5 = r.nextInt(90000) + 10000;
        ran4 = r.nextInt(9000) + 1000;
        ran3 = r.nextInt(900) + 100;
        ran2 = r.nextInt(90) + 10;
        ran1 = r.nextInt(9) + 1;
        str1 = String.valueOf(ran8);
        str2 = "0" + (String.valueOf(ran7));
        str3 = "0" + "0" + (String.valueOf(ran6));
        str4 = "0" + "0" + "0" + (String.valueOf(ran5));
        str5 = "0" + "0" + "0" + "0" + (String.valueOf(ran4));
        str6 = "0" + "0" + "0" + "0" + "0" + (String.valueOf(ran3));
        str7 = "0" + "0" + "0" + "0" + "0" + "0" + (String.valueOf(ran2));
        str8 = "0" + "0" + "0" + "0" + "0" + "0" + "0" + (String.valueOf(ran1));
        str9 = "0" + "0" + "0" + "0" + "0" + "0" + "0" + "1";
        str10 = Integer.toString(R.string.scrval);
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Режим помойки включен", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        textview.setText(str1);
        initiatePopupWindow();
        textview.setText(str2);
        delay();
        textview.setText(str3);
        delay();
        textview.setText(str4);
        delay();
        textview.setText(str5);
        delay();
        textview.setText(str6);
        delay();
        textview.setText(str7);
        delay();
        textview.setText(str8);
        delay();
        textview.setText(str9);
        delay();
        textview.setText(str10);
        }
    }
}
```

Не обращайте внимания, что в коде нет setOnClickListener. Я поставил атрибут в xml android:onclick. Кнопка нормально работает. Вылетает только если ввести "2014" и нажать на кнопку. На всех других значениях работает нормально.
Ошибка происходит именно в этих строках:

```
textview.setText(str1);
        initiatePopupWindow();
        textview.setText(str2);
        delay();
        textview.setText(str3);
        delay();
        textview.setText(str4);
        delay();
        textview.setText(str5);
        delay();
        textview.setText(str6);
        delay();
        textview.setText(str7);
        delay();
        textview.setText(str8);
        delay();
        textview.setText(str9);
        delay();
        textview.setText(str10);
```

Проверял способом комментирования строк. Даже если написать так:

```
textview.setText("Hello!");
```

Всё равно та же ошибка. Если эти строки закомментировать, то всё работает нормально. На всякий случай добавлю код strings.xml:

```
<resources>
<string name="app_name">Program 20000dgfg</string>
<string name="LoadButtonText">Загрузить</string>
<string name="CloseText">close</string>
<string name="scrap">scrapyard</string>
<string name="scrval">00000000</string>
```

И, конечно, standardscrapyard.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/popup_element"
android:background="#000000"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:weightSum="1">

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="80dp"
    android:layout_height="180dp"
    android:id="@+id/imageView"
    android:src="@drawable/tbo063krishka"
    android:contentDescription="@string/scrap"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="false"
    android:layout_marginLeft="12dp"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="66dp"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:text="@string/scrval"
    android:id="@+id/textView"
    android:textColor="#00c10a"
    android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="140dp"
    android:width="120dp"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/imageView"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Код ошибки:

> 03-30 15:42:37.594 14262-14262/com.testprogram.alex.program20000dgfg E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                                                                                          java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method for android:onClick
>                                                                                              at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:275)
>                                                                                              at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:3511)
>                                                                                              at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:14105)
>                                                                                              at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:605)
>                                                                                              at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
>                                                                                              at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
>                                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4600)
>                                                                                              at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>                                                                                              at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
>                                                                                              at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:809)
>                                                                                              at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:576)
>                                                                                              at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
>                                                                                           Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
>                                                                                              at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>                                                                                              at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
>                                                                                              at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:270)
>                                                                                              at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:3511) 
>                                                                                              at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:14105) 
>                                                                                              at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:605) 
>                                                                                              at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92) 
>                                                                                              at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137) 
>                                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4600) 
>                                                                                              at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
>                                                                                              at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511) 
>                                                                                              at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:809) 
>                                                                                              at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:576) 
>                                                                                              at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 
>                                                                                           Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
>                                                                                              at com.testprogram.alex.program20000dgfg.MainActivity.onClick(MainActivity.java:129)
>                                                                                              at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
>                                                                                              at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511) 
>                                                                                              at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:270) 
>                                                                                              at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:3511) 
>                                                                                              at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:14105) 
>                                                                                              at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:605) 
>                                                                                              at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92) 
>                                                                                              at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137) 
>                                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4600) 
>                                                                                              at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
>                                                                                              at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511) 
>                                                                                              at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:809) 
>                                                                                              at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:576) 
>                                                                                              at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

Код activity_main.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="com.testprogram.alex.program20000dgfg.MainActivity"
android:clickable="true">

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/LoadButtonText"
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="81dp"
    android:enabled="true"
    android:onClick="onClick"/>

<EditText
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/EditText"
    android:layout_above="@+id/button"
    android:layout_marginBottom="38dp"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/button"
    android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/button"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/button"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/button"
    android:inputType="text" />

<Spinner
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/MainSpinner"
    android:layout_marginTop="60dp"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/EditText"
    android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/EditText"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/EditText"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/EditText"
    android:popupBackground="#b60000" />

<Spinner
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/NewSpinner"
    android:layout_marginBottom="35dp"
    android:layout_above="@+id/EditText"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/EditText"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/EditText"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/EditText"
    android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/EditText"
    android:visibility="invisible"
    android:popupBackground="#a6ff9e" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Помогите мне, пожалуйста, разобраться с этой ошибкой!

Comment: Thread.sleep(600); в обработчике клика кнопки? Вы серьезно?

Comment: А что не так то? Не в этой строке ошибка, а в строках: textview.setText(str). Я хочу сделать, чтобы надпись на элементе менялось с интервалом 6/10 секунды. А у меня ошибка.

Comment: если закомментировать все delay(), работает?

Comment: Конечно, работает! Не в delay() дело, а в textview.setText(str).

Comment: Ещё раз вопрос - если закомментировать delay, но оставить textview.setText(str) - работает?

Comment: Нет, не работает. Ошибка уже без delay() была.

Comment: разметку `MainActivity` покажите, прозреваю, что там нет `textView`

Comment: @zRrr Этот textview в разметке standardscrapyard.xml. Activity_main.xml тут не причём. Но на всякий случай уже добавил. Смотрите в вопросе.

Comment: Ну я не настоящий андроид-программист, но `Activity.findViewById` возвращает view из того layout, который был загружен в `setContentView`, или `null`, если такого нет, что оно и проделывает. Вам может быть поможет `textview = (TextView) layout.findViewById(R.id.textView);` в `initiatePopupWindow`, и перенос вызова `initiatePopupWindow` до использования `textview`. А может и нет, у своего программиста спросите.

Comment: @zRrr На _layout_ программа ругается. Пишет: **qualifier must be an expression**. Пробовал написать так: **textvew = (textView) textview.findViewById(R.id.layout)** - всё равно та же ошибка. Ничего не помогает.((

Comment: У вас в логе написано: `Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException at com.testprogram.alex.program20000dgfg.MainActivity.onClick(MainActivity.java:129)` Т.е. что-то null на 129 строке в классе MainActivity. Укажите нам что это за строка. Также, устанавливать слушатель нажатий чрез xml - это очень плохая идея. Не надо так.

Comment: @ЮрийСПб На 129 строке: `str5 = "0" + "0" + "0" + "0" + (String.valueOf(ran4));`. Но он ругается сразу же со строки: `str1 = String.valueOf(ran8);`. Про слушатель - спасибо, попробую установить его в классе.

Comment: Вы уверены, что не вносили изменения в код и ошибка всё ещё на этой строке вылетает?

Comment: В код я вносил изменения, но ошибка именно на всех следующих строках, начиная со строки: `textview.setText(str1);`

Comment: Установил я слушатель button в класс. Стало ещё только хуже. Теперь приложение вообще не открывается. Сразу же вылетает с ошибкой. До этого было лучше. Оно хотя бы как-то работало, а теперь вообще никак.))

Comment: Пришлось отменить все изменения и сделать как было.

Comment: Стало не хуже, а лучше. Ошибка стала более локализованной. Вам надо ещё больше локализовать проблему. В тоннах вашего кода её сложно обнаружить.

Comment: @zRrr Вы были правы! Добавил так, как Вы сказали и код заработал. Только надо было указывать где и как вставить эти строки в код. А так спасибо, большое! Вопрос закрыт.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Итак из ошибки ясно что Ваш **textview == null**.

Попытаемся разобраться почему, для этого рассмотрим где он инициализируется:

### Место №1 - onCreate()

```
textview = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
```

Естественно тут `textview == null`, т.к. в `activity_main.xml` нет `TextView` c `id==textView`.

### Место №2 - initiatePopupWindow()

```
textview = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
```

Здесь мы снова ищем в `activity_main.xml`(!!!).
А Вам надо искать `TextView` на заинфлейттеном `standardscrapyard.xml`. Следовательно код `initiatePopupWindow()` должен выглядеть примерно так:

```
private void initiatePopupWindow() {
    try {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) MainActivity.this.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.standardscrapyard, (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.popup_element));
        textview = (TextView)layout.findViewById(R.id.textView);
        PopupWindow pwindo = new PopupWindow(layout, width, 180, true);
        pwindo.showAtLocation(layout, Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

---

Но даже после этого код будет все равно падать, т.к. Вы обращаетесь к `textview` еще до вызова `initiatePopupWindow()`:

```
textview.setText(str1);
initiatePopupWindow();
```

По видимому необходимо поменять эти строки местами.

Comment: Спасибо, большое! Приложение работает, но когда я ввожу то же **2014** и нажимаю на кнопку, телефон подвисает и android сразу же выполяняет последнюю строку: `textview.setText(str10);`. Я хочу сделать, чтобы надпись менялась каждые 600 миллисекунд, а он сразу меняет все значения и только потом, когда уже текст достиг последнего значения, появляется окно с последней строкой. Как этот казус исправить? Пробовал ставить задержку на 5 секунд - не помогает. :( Подскажите, пожалуйста!

Comment: @HybridTC25 Вам уже писали что использование `Thread.sleep(600);` в главном потоке и есть причина данного поведения.

Comment: Как это исправить? Скажите, пожалуйста! Мне нужно сделать, чтобы надпись на layout менялась через каждый промежуток.

Comment: @HybridTC25 как вариант можно использовать `Handler` и его метод `postDelayed()`

Comment: Как это добавить в мой код? Никак понять не могу. У меня ничего не получается.

Comment: @HybridTC25 что именно не получается? Как мне кажется это уже совершенно другой вопрос не относящийся к текущей теме, может быть стоит создать новую...

Comment: Не знаю  куда и как вставить в код. Компилятор выдаёт куча ошибок. Ладно создам новый вопрос.